# Titlebar not clickable with Form.TransparencyKey = White

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

If I create a C# (.NET 3.5) application using the WinForm template and set the Form.TransparencyKey property to White, the title bar and close,minimize,maximize -buttons does not work when running the application, a click on them results in the window losing focus in the same ways as clicking outside the window. There is no animation when the mouse is hovered over close etc.

This continues until the window is minimized (the button on the window does not work so it has to be done with winkey+m or through the taskbar) and then restored. After this the window appears to behave normal.

What is the mechanism behind this behavior?

Environment: Windows Vista (Aero) and VS2008.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any part of the window that matches the TransparencyKey color will be transparent to the user's eye.  And to the mouse, you'll click whatever window is underneath yours if you click on a part of the window that's transparent.

That makes using Color.White rather a bad choice for a color key, plenty of odds that the user's theme colors make parts of the title bar white as well.  Like the X in the Close button.

Pretty important that you pick a color that does *not* appear anywhere else in the window so you don't get accidental transparency.  The standard choice for such a color is Color.Fuchsia.  Nice fuchsed-up colors that normally burn a pinhole in the user's retina and nobody would voluntarily use in their UI designs.

---

One more excruciating detail: this kind of transparency, created by using *layered windows*, is implemented differently on modern Windows versions that have Aero enabled.  With Aero, it is no longer implemented by the video adapter but in software by the DWM.  Which has a bug, it doesn't correctly handle the mouse transparency for *certain* kinds of color key values.  This bug is not well characterized, but I know it doesn't work for Color.Red for example.  So picking the right key color is important.  Unless you want to take advantage of the bug, some programmers still want mouse events for transparent parts of the window.  Risky, but the bug has been around for many years now so is probably not going to get fixed anymore.

Comment: I understand transparency better now and it works as expected when using the Windows Classic theme. Using Aero it behaves as if the whole glass border of the window is white(and therefore transparent), but only for the mouse.

Comment: I don't edit a post by Hans to bold parts, so let me quote that to stress his point: _One more excruciating detail:..software ..which has a bug, it doesn't correctly handle the mouse transparency for certain kinds of color key values..Color.Red for example_ Been there, been bitten, now I know..

Answer (score 2):

Can't comment on answers yet so that "answer" is only a (detailed) comment to Hans Passant's answer. More specifically, that part:

> Which has a bug, it doesn't correctly handle the mouse transparency
>   for certain kinds of color key values. **This bug is not well
>   characterized**, but I know it doesn't work for Color.Red for example.
>   So picking the right key color is important. Unless you want to take
>   advantage of the bug, some programmers still want mouse events for
>   transparent parts of the window.

So here it is, I characterized the bug. Since I am talking about a bug, I feel it's important to mention that the following information is valid for .Net Framework 4.5 as of 02/06/2016.

The bug is actually more the standard than the exception since it occures for 255/256 (99.6%) of the colors, and for only 1/256 (0.4%) of the colors, it behaves the way it is documented.

The condition that distincts both cases is quite simple actually. If the Red component of the color is the same as the Blue component of the color (**Color.Red == Color.Blue**), the TransparencyKey will behave as it is documented:

> Any mouse actions, such as the click of the mouse, that are performed
>   on the transparent areas of the form will be transferred to the
>   windows below the transparent area.

As a result, most of the greyish, greenish and purplish colors (including Color.Fuchsia = **255**,0,**255** as mentionned in Hans' answer)

Any other color will feature the bug and all mouse events will occure on the transparent control. In other words, if you want to take advantage of the bug, simply ensure to choose a color where the Red component is different then the Blue component (**Color.Red != Color.Blue**).

Since I might be the first one to document that bug, I cannot quote any reference, but all 16,777,216 RGB combinations have been tested programmatically and as a result, that correlation as shown to be valid 100% of the times.

Hoping that knowing the rule behind the bug will help someone choose a color wisely instead of trying lots of colors randomly until he meets the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

1)The Form has two properties called Minimize Box and Maximize-box, set both of them to true.

2)else set ControlBox property to true.